# Jquery Animate - Making the element bounce just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have got a box `.child`. I want this box to jump and then come back to it's original location, when the key up is pressed. I have got the following script:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function( e ){
    if ( e.keyCode === 38 ) {
        $('.child').animate({ 
            'bottom' : '50px'
        }, 250).animate({
            'bottom' : '0px' 
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

Now it does make the element bounce when the up key is pressed. But if I keep hitting the up key again and again it keeps making the box jump again and again even after the key is not being pressed. Now I know about the `queue` so I tried the following:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function( e ){
    if ( e.keyCode === 38 ) {
        $('.child').animate({ 
            'bottom' : '50px'
        }, {
            duration: 250,
            queue: false
        }).animate({
            'bottom' : '0px' 
        }, {
            duration: 250,
            queue: false
        });
    }
});
```

But it didn't work as expected either. Then I thought to add the `queue : false` to second animate only but still it didn't work. Can anyone please tell me how can I make the element jump once instead of the repeated jumps?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/duwtbux0/

Comment: Sorry, but I cant reproduce your problem (on FF 24). The box jumps exactly once per button press (it will queue further presses). If I hold the button it will count all repeats and jump once for each.

Comment: That's his problem, he doesn't want to queue up a bunch of jumps. http://jsfiddle.net/duwtbux0/2/

Comment: @CBauer Hm, I read the problem differently: `it keeps making the box jump [...] even after the key is not being pressed`

Comment: Right, and the reason it keeps jumping is because the animations are queued up when you hold down the up key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add some kind of flag that will stop input from being accepted.

```
var acceptingInput = true;
$(document).on('keydown', function( e ){

    if(acceptingInput){
        if ( e.keyCode === 38 ) {
            acceptingInput = false;
            $('.child').animate({ 
                'bottom' : '50px'
            }, 250).animate({
                'bottom' : '0px' 
            }, 250, function() {
                acceptingInput = true;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/duwtbux0/2/

Comment: But...this doesn't work...please check the fiddle...cheers :)

Comment: Works fine in chrome, firefox and ie. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If you want, here is another possibility:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function( e ){
    if ( e.keyCode === 38 ) {
        $('.child').stop(1,0).animate({ 
            'bottom' : '50px'
        }, 250).animate({
            'bottom' : '0px' 
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

Adding the [.stop(1,0)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) will keep the block in the air as long as you repeatedly press the up key and will also stop queuing.

http://jsfiddle.net/duwtbux0/5/

This might not be what you are looking for, but it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Pretty cool actually, though it doesn't work for me in chrome until the second bounce which is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the box bounce only onces, you need to unbind the keydown listener on document.

```
$(document).on('keydown.bounce', function( e ){
    if ( e.keyCode === 38 ) {
        $('.child').animate({ 
            'bottom' : '50px'
        }, 250).animate({
            'bottom' : '0px' 
        }, 250);
        $(document).unbind('.bounce');
    }
});
```

The queue property isn't meant to do what you want. The queue is only designed to tell jquery whether you want to execute animation right now or after the last one finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keydown', function( e ){
    if($('.child').css('bottom') === '0px'){
    if ( e.keyCode === 38 ) {
        $('.child').animate({ 
            'bottom' : '50px'
        }, 250).animate({
            'bottom' : '0px' 
        }, 250);
    }
    }
});
```

This works fine for me!!